# “Connection refused” error when connecting to local MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am having this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306)
```

I saw a similar question and I tried the solution by changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, but it is still not working. I am using Mac OS X Lion. Please any help would be appreciated

This is the PHP code I use to connect:

```php
<?php
    require("constants.php");
    // open database
    $connect = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die('error connecting: ' . mysql_error());
    // select database
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die('error selecting db: ' . mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Is your database server really listening on TCP port 3306 on the same machine?  Try connecting to to mysql from the terminal, explicitly specifying the host and port

Comment: Is your database really running? Check using `ps -elf | grep mysql`. You should have two results.

Comment: @i.am.michiel when i checked i had this result                     501   281   277     4006   0  31  0  2434892    540 -      R+   ffffff800b80e440 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql        1:09pm

Comment: Your MySQL server is not launched. Start it.

Comment: @i.am.michiel you re right thanks michaels

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure your firewall if open to connections on port 3306.

The command should be `ipfw set enable 3306`, but if you want you can read more about actually [setting the firewall permissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html).

Another thing could be to make sure MySQL is listening on port 3306, edit the [my.ini](http://opensourcedba.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/mysql-basics-part-3-%E2%80%93-your-my-cnf-or-my-ini-file/) file and set

```
[client]
port=3306
```

And then restart MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before. You can fix it by commenting out "skip-networking" in the configuration. (my.ini or my.cnf, it's /etc/mysql/my.cnf on Linux, not sure about Mac)

-- edit
Also, you can try typing "netstat" in the Terminal, to make sure that mysql is listed there (should be something like 127.0.0.1:mysql or 127.0.0.1:3306). If it is not listed, MySQL either hasn't started, or hasn't been able to bind.

Comment: i typed netstat and the closest i got in the list is tcp4       0      0  localhost.49153        localhost.1023         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.1023         localhost.49153        ESTABLISHED